# python RarFile extract just 1 directory with file inside dir

Tags: python, winrar

rar file in test.rar file have more 10 directory  i need extract just alex directory with file inside alex

```
import rarfile
with rarfile.RarFile('test.rar', 'r') as r:
    for file in r.namelist():
        if file.endswith('/'):
            print (file)
            if "alex/" in file:
                r.extract(file)
```

tools extract just folder witout files

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you run `r.extract(file)` inside `if file.endswith('/'):` - so it runs it only for folder. Maybe you should runt `extract` without `if file.endswith('/'):`

Comment: or maybe you should use `not` in line `if not file.endswith('/'):` to work only with files.

Answer (score 0):

You run `r.extract(file)` inside `if file.endswith('/'):` - so it runs it only for folder.

Maybe you could run `extract()` without `if file.endswith('/'):`

```
import rarfile

with rarfile.RarFile('test.rar') as r:
    for file in r.namelist():
        if 'alex/' in file:
            print(file)
            r.extract(file)
```

To skip folders you may use `not` in `if not file.endswith('/'):`

```
import rarfile

with rarfile.RarFile('test.rar') as r:
    for file in r.namelist():
        if not file.endswith('/'):  # `not` - to skip folders
            if 'alex/' in file:
                print(file)
                r.extract(file)
```